# Algorithm of unique user identity

Tags: security, math

I'm writing service for anonymous commenting (plugin for social network).
I have to generate pseudo-unique number for the each user per a thread.

So, each post has a unique number (for example, 6345) and each user has unique id (9144024). Using this information I need to generate unique index in array of avatars.

Let's say, there is array with 312 images, it's static and all images are in the same order every time.

Now the algorithm looks like this:

```
(post id + user id) % number if images = index

(6345 + 9144024) % 312 = 33
```

And in comment I show image with index 33. The problem is that it's possible to find the `user id` by the image if someone will find the way of generating images (image list is always in same order).

What is the best way here without storing per-post data in database, for example.

Comment: I think you have to put randomness into it. otherwise you will be able to get the user id (if one can get enough information). Maybe you can just pick a random image and mark it as "in use" for this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a kind of one-way function: computing the image id from the user id should be easy, but not the converse. The first thing that comes to my mind here is using hash functions: simply concatenate the user id and the post id, perhaps with some salt, then compute the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash of that, and take that modulo the number of images.

In this approach, I'd interpret the hash result as a single 160-bit integer. If you don't have a big integer library at hand, you can do the modulo computation incrementally. Start with the highest byte, and then in each step multiply the current value by 2<sup>8</sup>, add the next byte, and reduce the sum modulo 312. You could also simply take the lowest 32 or 64 bit or something like that, and perform the modulo on that, although the result of that approach might be less evenly distributed than the one outlined above.